# cannot access static method from in non static context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have the following peace of code

```
namespace myProject.Core
{
    public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
    {
        public static ProfileCommon CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
            }
        }
        public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string userName)
        {
            return (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(userName);
        }
    }
}
```

And below is a snippet of code in my view.

```
           <div class="myClass">
                @{
                    string userName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session[Sessions.UserName]);
                    ProfileCommon Profile1 = new ProfileCommon();
                    ProfileCommon Profile = Profile1 .GetProfile(userName);
                    }
                    string displayUserName = User.Identity.Name;
                }
            </div>
```

However, i'm getting an error at the line

> prf1.GetProfile(userName);

The error is "***cannot access static method GetProfile from in non static context***"

This error only occurs in Visual studio 2013 but the same code works fine with out any error in visual studio 2010.

Comment: you cant access the static method from a class you instantiate. you need to declare ProfileCommon as a static class however you would not be able to derive from ProfileBase. I also believe you aren't correctly using inheritance here either. Any reason why you have static properties in an inaccessible non static class?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas the same code works in a Visual studio 2010 project.

Comment: doesn't mean newer versions could have bugs :) Did you upgrade the .NET Version? I don't understand how it could work on .NET 4.0 (if you were using it in VS2010). I also noticed you re-edited your post so now your error message is invalid altogether. I don't see "prf1"

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, both the VS 2010 & VS 2013 projects are targeting .NET 4.0